# Create from another controllers view with validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Iam trying to create agents from my bills show. I cant show validation errors on my form, I can only flash them.
I tried to do the form only with `@agent`, to render and not to redirect, to pass bill id in form...but I dont get it.
How can I create an agent and return to bill show view with my validation errors in the form?

### CONTROLLERS

bills_Controler.rb

```
def show
    @bill = Bill.find(params[:id])
    @agent = @bill.agent || Agent.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.pdf do
        render pdf: @bill.to_filename
              end
      format.zip { send_zip }
    end
end
```

agents_controller.rb

```
def create
    @agent = Agent.new
    @bill=Bill.find(params[:bill_id])

    if build_agent(agent_params).save
        flash[:notice] = t('agent.saved')
            redirect_to bill_path (params[:billid])
    else
        #flash[:error] = @agent.errors
        #render 'bills/show'
        redirect_to bill_path(@bill), :flash => { :error => @agent.errors.full_messages.join(', ') }
    end
end
```

### VIEWS

_bill.html.erb

```
<%= render 'bills/show/agents'%>
```

_agents.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for [@bill, @agent] do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :name, wrapper_html: { class: 'medium' } %>
    <%= f.input :surname, wrapper_html: { class: 'medium' } %>
    <%= f.input :phone_number, wrapper_html: { class: 'medium' }  %>
    <%= f.button :submit, class: 'button btn-main btn btn-primary'%>
<%end%>
```

### MODELS

bill.rb

```
belongs_to :agent, inverse_of: :bills
```

agent.rb

```
has_many :bills, inverse_of: :agents, dependent: :restrict_with_error
validates :name ,presence: true ....
```

### ROUTES

```
resources :bills, only: [:index, :show, :new, :create, :update] do
    resources :agents, only: [:new, :update,:create]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to show errors in the fields you need `render` `show` action with the same object which contains errors:

```
def show
  # show action code goes here
end

def create
  @agent = Agent.new(agent_params)
  @bill = Bill.find(params[:bill_id])

  if @agent.save 
    # validation fails and  
    # the @agent object contains errors
    @bill.agent = @agent
    flash[:notice] = t('agent.saved')
    redirect_to bill_path(params[:bill_id])
  else
    render :new
    # because the new action contains a form
  end
end
```

Comment: the form is in my bill show, so when it fails I want to show the bills show again. I dont have agents/new tamplate, I want to do both on same page, bills show page.

Comment: render show action, keep in mind you need have the same variables.

Comment: If I render 'bills/show' I get url /bill/:id/agents and I get trouble with other form route that assigns agent to bill.   patch 'bills/:id/agent_assign' => 'bills#agent_assign'. Because controller changes to agent controller.

Comment: I know nothig about your app logic. In order to show errors in the form you need pass variable with errors to the form.

Comment: and I can do it without changing URL, staying in bill/:id ??